# How can I select the first value from dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I have array of object there I am populating data through `.map()` function I want to select by default first value of my dropdown and also need to get first option attribute values.  I tried very hard but did not find a specific solution. Could someone please help me how to achieve my goal?

**Code**

```
  <select className="form-control input-box" {...input} required>
    <option>Select Manager</option>
    {managerList.map((item, index) => (
      <option
        value={item.id}
        managerZoneId={item.zoneId}
        key={item.id}

      >
        {item.firstName + " " + item.lastName}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

Comment: Actually, your first option is selected by default.

Comment: @Striped Thank You for reply but  it not working as I expect

Comment: If you do not specify any default value, by default you should get the first option as selected only.

Comment: So what is the default option selected ?

Comment: Post complete code. Including Select tag...

Comment: @Soham I just updated my question please look at a full code

Comment: @kokila I want to achieve same goal , How I can select first option by default

Comment: @Striped Actually, it will be the first option of the dropdown

Comment: Use `defaultValue={/* one of the option's value prop */}` prop on `select`.

Comment: what should I consider in defaultValue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select className="form-control input-box" {...input} required
   defaultValue={managerList[0].id} // Add this line
>
    <option>Select Manager</option>
    {managerList.map((item, index) => (
      <option
        value={item.id}
        managerZoneId={item.zoneId}
        key={item.id}

      >
        {item.firstName + " " + item.lastName}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for line actually I am using redux form it working fine I mean default value has been selected but I did not retrieve this dropdown menu otherelse

Comment: @Jonas try motivating those who help by upvoting and accepting the answer if it helps.

Comment: Sure, I will do . Could you please help me in this issue .

Comment: @Jonas If you have further issue please either update question with more specifics/details or open new issue.